# Caller or Receiver can't hear my voice in Moto G 2nd Gen 2014 running Lollipop

Tags: calls, motorola-moto-g2

The Caller or Receiver can't hear my voice but I can hear them. It seems to be a kind of software bug because when I do some recording the mic works perfectly.

The only problem that I noticed is my voice is not getting through on the phone calls. I checked the microphone sign in the dialer mode, and it is not disabled too. I have all my contacts and important messages, and I simply don't want to do the factory reset, unless it is really required and is helpful too. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue. I managed to fix it by simply restarting phone... but if that doesn't work then I would suggest a factory reset.